# SwiftUI List refresh in background on iOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I found some weird bug in SwiftUI on iOS 16.

I am using CoreData for database.
I have main screen with list of items and toolbar menu with actions.

[image: List 1]

I can switch there to editMode of List. When I turn it on, list is re-rendered and correct accessory for moving of rows is shown.

[image: List 2]

I add new item to database on pushed form screen. I return to list. I see added new item on it. I try to switch to edit mode, but "nothing" happens.

[[image: New item]

EditMode is turned on, but cells are not re-rendered with correct accessory.

[image: List 3]

It is was working correctly before I add new item.

After some force re-rendering, like remove of item from database, accessory in edit mode is shown correctly.

It's looks like List re-render in background create weird behavior of List.

I tried it on iOS 15.6 simulator and it was working correctly.

Where can be problem?

Pseudo code:

List

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [
                    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.id, ascending: true)
                  ]
    ) var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @State var editMode = EditMode.inactive
    @State var goNewItem = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { frame in
                ZStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                            //  Render cell
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        goNewItem.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Image("add")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .padding(20)
                        }
                        .background(Color.primaryColor)
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                        .shadow(radius: 4)
                    }
                    .position(x: frame.size.width - 50, y: frame.size.height-50)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .foregroundColor(.secondaryTextColor)
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(), isActive: $goNewItem) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    .hidden()
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add item

```
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var note: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                // inputs
                TextArea("Note", text: $note)
                    .frame(minHeight: 30)
                
                Button {
                    save()
                } label: {
                    Text(Strings.shortcut_button_save.uppercased())
                        .padding(4)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
    
    private func save() {
        withAnimation {
            do {
                let item = Item(context: viewContext)
                item.note = note
                
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I needed refresh List by force.

I added

```
@State private var refreshingID = UUID()
```

Updated List with id

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
    ...
}.id(refreshingID)
```

And I added to view with list

```
.onAppear {
    self.refreshingID = UUID()
}
```

This forcefully refreshed List